# Getting the size of a stack in python

Tags: python, stack

The question from my professor was to create a function that would get the size of a stack in python, as opposed to creating a method in the class. If I were to create a method to get the size in the class then I could just do return len(self._items), however we were asked to create a function outside of the class.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
def size(s: Stack) -> int:
    """
    Returns the size of the stack.
    """
    count = 0
    while not s.is_empty():
        s.pop()
        count += 1
    return count
```

But the problem is that the stack becomes empty at the end. My question was, what can I do to preserve the contents of stack?
We were also given a hint to start by creating a stack object but I was confused on what that looks like, for example if I did `p = Stack()` and I added this just before the counter, would this be a stack object or stack instance? I am a bit confused between object and instance.

Edit: I think I have completed the implementation, I just need someone to confirm if I have done it correctly.

```
def size(s: Stack) -> int:
    """
    Returns the size of the stack.
    """
    temp_stack = Stack()
    count = 0
    while not s.is_empty():
        temp_stack.push(s.pop())
        count += 1
    
    while not temp_stack.is_empty():
        s.push(temp_stack.pop())
    return count
```

Comment: If you can execute `len(self._items)` in the disallowed class, then you can execute `len(s._items)` in this function.

Comment: Is creating a copy of the original Stack allowable and emptying out this new stack? Are there any other class methods or instance variables exposed that can be of help? Is the size of the Stack inspectable in any other way?

Comment: Yes, creating a copy is allowed, I am just not sure how that would look like in my code.

Comment: If this is an exercise in writing data types and working against abstractions rather than, say, finding creative ways around the problem (because you just happen to be using Python), think about what happens when you `pop`. It will return you an item and remove it from the `Stack` - and you will get the things returned in the reverse order you put them into the `Stack`. And then eventually you need to restore these items to the original `Stack s` your method received. If you push items onto a temporary stack as you're popping them from the original, do you see how you can restore the original?

Comment: @MichaelRuth I cannot execute len(s._items) in my code because _items is a private attribute, which is why my professor wanted it as a function as opposed to a method.

Comment: Python doesn't have private attributes, the `_` is merely a polite suggestion. Even `__` isn't private, just obscure.

Comment: Also, an object is an instance of a class - if you're unclear about some of the terminology, I'd recommend [reading some of the Python `class` tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects). Writing `p = Stack()` is creating an instance  object of a `Stack` and assigning the reference to `p`.

Comment: @Sabrina `Stack` is not a python datatype, so we don't know what it can do other than the two methods you showed us `pop()` and `is_empty()`. Can it do anything else?

Comment: If the only way to access the elements of `Stack` is to `pop()`, then `Stack.pop()` and store the elements in a `collections.deque`, get the length of `collections.deque`, put the elements from the `deque` back into the `Stack` in the correct order and call it a day,

Comment: @Mark it can also push

Comment: So make a temp stack `temp_stack = Stack()` then as you count the items do `temp_stack.push(s.pop())`.  Then once you've counted, do the opposite: `while not temp_stack.is_empty(): s.push(temp_stack.pop())` to restore the stack.

Comment: Like the other commenters, I'm beginning to think your professor wants you to `Stack.pop()` pop out the Stack until empty into another Stack using `Stack.push()`, make a count of the number of pops, then restack the original Stack using `pop` and `push` again.

Comment: @Mark and Aeronautix  thank you for your help, I did it this way and it seemed to work!!